# How to get Range from A2 to End (No select statement)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy and paste from one workbook to another workbook, but I am getting Autofilter method of Range class failed error. I found out that this error occurs when I do not specify my end row. For example if my copying data field ends at row 500, I have to set my Range exactly (A2,AJ500). However, this data (end row) can be changed every month. It could be AJ700, AJ600, etc. Is there a way to make my range(A2, End Row) and make macro to run without Range class failed error?

Please let me know if you are not clear with my question. Thanks.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()


    Dim wb As Workbook, wbO As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet


    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Copyingfrom")


    Set wbO = Workbooks.Add("Output.xlsm")


    With wbO

        Set wsO = wbO.Sheets("OutputSheet")
        ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

With ws.Range("A2:AJ500") --> this is the field that I want to run as something like (A2:end) 

        .AutoFilter Field:=36, Criteria1:="1"
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        End With

        wsO.Range("I3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
    xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    End With


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

## Copy to Workbook

### The Code

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyRange()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
    Dim lngLastRow As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Copyingfrom")
    Set wsO = Workbooks("Output.xlsm").Sheets("OutputSheet")

    With ws
        lngLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        With .Range("A2:AJ" & lngLastRow)
            .AutoFilter Field:=36, Criteria1:="1"
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        End With
        wsO.Range("I3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way:

```
With ws.Range("A2").CurrentRegion ...
```

This will automatically define your range no matter which your last row is.